# epoll_wait() wakes up on EPOLLIN even I have consumed all reader buffer

Tags: sockets

Hello there I am getting mad with this issue since I'm using a simple pattern.
Ok, I have a infinite while in which I use epoll_wait on server socket and already connected sockets. All went ok if a new socket send a connection request; my problem is when connected sockets (right now I am just using one socket sending 390k packet) sends data: doesn't matter if I use EPOLLONESHOT or EPOLLET, after consumed all request buffer on that socket, rearming socket or receiving EAGAIN on recv(), epoll_wait always wakes up again with wrong buffer!
My server works with threadpool, but right now is just one thread that does all work (to simplify testing):

```
while (TRUE) {
        int num = epoll_wait(efd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) { // ciclo epoll()
            if (events[i].events & EPOLLERR || events[i].events & EPOLLHUP || !(events[i].events & EPOLLIN)) {
                fprintf (stderr, "epoll error on socket: closed\n");
                s = epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, events[i].data.fd, NULL);
            }
            else if (events[i].data.fd == serverSocket) { 
                while (TRUE) {
                    newInfoClient = server->m_bgServer->AcceptClient(&newSocketClient);
                    if (newInfoClient == NULL) { // nessun client
                        break;
                    }
                    else { 
                            printf("\nSocket accettato: %d", newSocketClient);
                            s = CSocket::MakeNonBlocking(newSocketClient);
                            if (s == -1)
                                abort();
                            event.data.fd = newSocketClient;
                            event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
                            s = epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, newSocketClient, &event);
                            if (s == -1) {
                                abort();
                            }
                } 
            }
            else { 
                AbstractTcpServerGame::DownloadTcpRequest(client);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have just omitted some checks and other internal codes.
    AbstractTcpServerGame::DownloadTcpRequest(...)
This function is just a recv in loop to rescues my own header, get buffer body and just to verify empty buffer outside loop I call a simple recv() that returns -1 (errno=EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK).
After this when I rearm the socket with epoll_ctr() in DownloadTcpRequest() in EPOLLONESHOT case, when it returns epoll_wait() wakes up again on the same socket!! this is my execution log:

```
New socket (6) request (errno 11)  <--- when epoll_wait() emits EPOLLIN on socket 6
Download of 18 bytes (socket 6) <-- inside AbstractTcpServerGame::DownloadTcpRequest()
Download of 380k (socket 6) <-- another recv() loop to rescue body request
------------------- empty buffer on socket 6 ----------- <-- dummy recv to show empty buffer
New socket (6) request (errno 11)  
Download of 18 bytes (socket 6) 
Download of -1556256155 (socket 6) 
Error on socket 6 (bad::alloc exception)
```

Client sends 398k (18 header + body) and all data are correctly received as shown above, but rearming socket or using EPOLLET, epoll_wait() generates another request and I don't know where those are taken infact are not correct!